# Как подключить к проекту Awesomium?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, awesomium

я пробовал в NuGet консоли прописать "Install-Package Neutronium.WebBrowserEngine.Awesomium", скачались несколько библиотек, но в Toolbox элементы браузера не появились. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Скачал отдельное Awesomium SDK и установил его, после этого все элементы появились в проекте